# RVM not recognizing gemset?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

After creating the gemset, cd out of and back into the folder throws the error that the gemset does not exist.

Here is my shell session

```
dewet-mac:~ dewet$ cd ruby/routerscript/
Gemset 'routerscript' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create routerscript' first, or append '--create'.
dewet-mac:routerscript dewet$ rvm gemset create routerscript
gemset created routerscript => /Users/dewet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript
dewet-mac:routerscript dewet$ cd ..
dewet-mac:ruby dewet$ cd routerscript/
Gemset 'routerscript' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create routerscript' first, or append '--create'.
```

When I check in `/Users/dewet/.rvm/gems/` the gem exists as `ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript`

How do I fix this?

Comment: what kind of project file do you use? is it `.rvmrc` - can you show its content.

Comment: Thank you @mpapis, that answered my question, I am new to RVM and I did not understand that the error was in response to not finding the gemset as specified in the .rvmrc file, I had rvm `1.9.3@routerscript` in the .rvmrc file. Changed it to `rvm ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript` and it worked immediately. I would vote up your comment if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was is in response to not finding the Gemset that was specified in the .rvmrc project file. Edited the file to contain `rvm ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript`. That fixed it.

This implies silent `use`:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript
```

To allow automatic creation of gemsets use `--create`:

```
rvm --create ruby-2.0.0-p0@routerscript
```

To avoid trusting and not creating gemsets use `.ruby-version` / `.ruby-gemset`:

```
rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version
```

It will automatically migrate your `.rvmrc` to the new format.

More details at RVM site: https://rvm.io

Answer (score 3):

If you've only just installed RVM, make sure you restart your terminal.